# PHP + MSQL + Function use request in a function

Tags: php, sql, function, pdo

Guys, I want to correct this function **the request from DB its works fine** but I want to use it as a function so I can repeat it 30 times

the problem here is I don't know really how to use it into a function

```
<?php

        $today = date("Y-m-d") ;

        function getDateFunc($today) {

        $getttlprice = "SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice FROM orders WHERE ldate = :today";
        $ttp = $pdo->prepare($getttlprice);
        $ttp->execute(array(':today'=>$today));
        $resultttp =  $ttp->fetchObject();
        $todayresulte = $resultttp->TotalPrice;
        echo $todayresulte ;
        }

        getDateFunc('16-06-2018') ;

     ?>
```

normally the function is like this but I don't know how to use it with my requst

```
function getDateFunc($today){
  echo $today ; // resulte 16/06/2018 by today time
}
```

[image]

Comment: i think that you are not giving connection

Comment: There is no database connection tool in the function. You can call the database connection code with `global`. Also your date format appears to be incorrect. Today: _year, month and day_ but yor write; _day, month and year_

Comment: It is not advised to use the `global` keyword. Instead I suggest using a wrapper class to put your function into as a public method and pass the instantiated PDO connection object to the constructor.

Comment: For simplicity sake you would need to pass your `$pdo` variable as an argument to your function so that is accessible without using the `global` keyword. ie.  `function getDateFunc($today, $pdo){ /*...*/ }` Then use it `require_once 'connect.php'; getDateFunc('2018-06-16', $pdo);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

you have to give connection in $pdo

Comment: yeah oh i have to put the the include "connect.php" ; into the function i didnt know about that

Answer (score 0):

There is no database connection constructor in the function. You can call the database connection code with `global` or in the function.

Also your date format appears to be incorrect.

Today: *year, month and day* but you write; *day, month and year*

```
 function getDateFunc($today) {

     try {
        $pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password); 
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        echo "Connected successfully"; 
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }


    $getttlprice = "SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice FROM orders WHERE ldate = :today";
    $ttp = $pdo->prepare($getttlprice);
    $ttp->execute(array(':today'=>$today));
    $resultttp =  $ttp->fetchObject();
    $todayresulte = $resultttp->TotalPrice;
    echo $todayresulte ;
}
```

Comment: yeah oh i have to put the the include "connect.php" ; into the function i didnt know about that